# Read external properties in executeScript processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an external properties file configured in nifi.properties in nifi.variable.registry.properties . I want to read this property in executeScript processor in python. I have used 
`str(context.getProperty('URL'))` but its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.9.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html

---

- declare a dynamic property for the ExecuteScript processor.
  for example `VAR_URL = ${URL}`
- then inside script you can access this property: 
  `VAR_URL.evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).getValue()`

---

or if you don't want to declare property for your processor and you are sure the property declared somewhere, then you can use the following code:

```
context.newPropertyValue( '${URL}' ).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()
```

> Note: don't use double quotes around `${URL}` because this expression will be processed as a groovy-string before evaluating nifi expression...

Comment: In executescript I used to write
IP = context.newPropertyValue("${IP}").evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue() for Python script
But now I am trying the same in executegroovyscript it is not working. I saw the samples which are same as above code for groovy but it does not work

Comment: It throws groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: IP.. Even tried context.getProperty("${IP}").evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue(), throws same exception

Comment: Oh, there was a mistake: use single quotes for this string: `context.getProperty('${IP}')....` because with double quotes the `${}` processed as groovy expression. With double quotes it should not work in both cases... Going to change answer.

Comment: how can i use this in static block class Const{
 static String ip = context.getProperty('${IP}').evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();}
}

Comment: there is no `context` in a static block unless it's a `static onStart(ProcessContext context){...}` method in `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor. Example see here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Tried this static onStart(ProcessContext context){
    Const.ip = context.newPropertyValue('${IP}').evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();}. It does not throw any error but does not return value, returns null

Comment: And what's the value of the IP property and where it's defined?

Comment: IP=192.168.0.0.1 is in custom.properties file which is configured in nifi.properties  nifi.variable.registry.properties=D:\\nifi-1.9.2\\conf\\custom.properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192999/discussion-between-happy-and-daggett).

Comment: it works for me (nifi 1.9.1). better to change path in this property `nifi.variable.registry.properties=D:\\nifi-1.9.2\\conf\\custom.properties` to this one: `nifi.variable.registry.properties=./conf/custom.properties`